# Dockerfile permission denied error (Streamlit / OpenShift)

Tags: bash, git, docker, dockerfile, openshift

I used this template Dockerfile from https://docs.streamlit.io/knowledge-base/tutorials/deploy/kubernetes to create a container. The build runs through and is passed, but the container/pod shows an error concerning run.sh:

Error: container create failed: time="2023-11-07T23:40:52Z" level=error msg="runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "./run.sh": permission denied"

Whats the problem here?

Please respect to the very small changes in the Dockerfile, because I cannot use git clone there. But this is not the question - the question it why this "template" offered from streamlit does not work.

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

RUN groupadd --gid 1000 appuser \
    && useradd --uid 1000 --gid 1000 -ms /bin/bash appuser

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade \
    pip \
    virtualenv

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    software-properties-common \
    git

USER appuser
WORKDIR /home/appuser

# DELETED, BECAUSE NO REPO-ACCESS
RUN git clone https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit-example.git app

#THEREFORE ADDED (hope this is similar to the repo clone with ./app/?)
COPY main.py ./app/
COPY requirements.txt ./app/

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/appuser/venv
RUN virtualenv ${VIRTUAL_ENV}
RUN . ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/activate && pip install -r app/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501

COPY run.sh /home/appuser
ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

The file run.sh is also from the page above an shown here:

```
#!/bin/bash

APP_PID=
stopRunningProcess() {
    # Based on https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-propagate-a-signal-to-child-processes-from-a-bash-script
    if test ! "${APP_PID}" = '' && ps -p ${APP_PID} > /dev/null ; then
       > /proc/1/fd/1 echo "Stopping ${COMMAND_PATH} which is running with process ID ${APP_PID}"

       kill -TERM ${APP_PID}
       > /proc/1/fd/1 echo "Waiting for ${COMMAND_PATH} to process SIGTERM signal"

        wait ${APP_PID}
        > /proc/1/fd/1 echo "All processes have stopped running"
    else
        > /proc/1/fd/1 echo "${COMMAND_PATH} was not started when the signal was sent or it has already been stopped"
    fi
}

trap stopRunningProcess EXIT TERM

source ${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/activate

streamlit run ${HOME}/app/main.py &
APP_ID=${!}

wait ${APP_ID}#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the Dockerfile contains an appropriate statement for granting permissions.

Add this command and run script again:

`RUN chmod +x /home/appuser/run.sh`

Comment: Ok, I  tested this, but get also an error:
changing permissions of '/home/appuser/run.sh' Operation not permitted
Tried the docker generation also with ``` sudo docker build -t <tag> . ``` with the same result

Comment: where in the dockerfile did you put the `chmod` ? I guess you put it somewhere after you switched the User. This has to be done before the `USER appuser`